# Where and how can seismic data for earthquakes and volcanoes be downloaded?

Tags: seismology, earthquakes, open-data, data-formats

I need it in this format.
[image]

I went to USGS and IRIS websites but couldn't understand the downloading procedure

Comment: Do you want data, or images of processed data? Maybe you can clarify. I'm afraid I don't know about finding ready-processed stuff, but if you know Python you can get more or less anything you need from dozens of open data sources through [the excellent ObsPy package](http://docs.obspy.org/gallery.html).

Comment: i need data.Images can be generated from it

Comment: OK, it makes it easier if you can generate your own spectra, plots, etc. [Have a look at this tutorial...](http://docs.obspy.org/tutorial/code_snippets/retrieving_data_from_datacenters.html) Does ObsPy meet your needs?

Comment: It would be good to know if you got anywhere in your quest.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to look at earthquake data that you would like in a data set you can work on (filter,plot,process,etc.) is three steps.

1. Get yourself a copy of Matlab
2. Go to the iris website and download a program called IrisFetch.m (see http://ds.iris.edu/ds/nodes/dmc/manuals/) .
3. Next you need a list of events and a list of stations from which to download the event, both of these can be gained simultaneously with a program from iris called Jweed. Just download both lists into a cvs file and import to Matlab and run through IrisFetch. This requires a very basic understanding of programming in Matlab but its not hard to figure out at all. Later on you will learn that you don't need Jweed at all to do this but instead can do it all through IrisFetch. Jweed is popular and easy to use though.

If this is too complicated, you can use the web-based part of iris to look at specific earthquakes at specific stations. But I don't think you get to interact with the data this way.