# Querying Seismic Databases

Tags: geophysics, seismology, database

I'm trying to find 3-component records of the P-wave arrivals of a variety of earthquakes at seismic stations (specific earthquakes or stations aren't important, I just want a small library of these arrivals for a machine learning project). I expected there would be labeled databases of this kind of thing where I could simply browse by earthquake or station and download the data. However the request process appears much more complicated and honestly I'm very confused.

Is anyone familiar with how to query these databases?

Comment: Just want to connect with [this (unanswered) question](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/where-and-how-can-seismic-data-for-earthquakes-and-volcanoes-be-downloaded); also see ObsPy, mentioned in the comments there.

Answer (score 4):

Unless they are large or famous earthquakes, I doubt you will find the waveforms for specific earthquakes.

What you will find is a ton of seismic data: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/data/?source=sitenav

which you can request. Once you have requested (downloaded ect) the waveforms (probably in seed format) you will need to analyze the waveforms themselves to find specific earthquakes (request data from a time when you know there was an earthquake) and find the p/s/love ect wave yourself on the seismogram.

To read seed data, you can either find a matlab code or write your own! (Im sure there is a python equivalent at this point.)